# Why does my program print out the exception statement endlessly give bad user input?

Tags: java, exception

Ive no idea if my title made sense but here is the code ©

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gussing {
    public static void theGame(Scanner input){
        int randomNum= (int)(Math.random()*101);//randomizes a number between 0-100 inclusive of both
        System.out.println(randomNum); //for debugging purposes
        int attemptCounter = 0; //counts how many attempts the user make
        System.out.print("Welcome to the guess-the number game! Enter your guess: ");

        while(true){
            System.out.println("here is bad input");
            try{
                System.out.println("here is after the bad input");
                int userInput= input.nextInt();
                if (userInput==randomNum) //when usr input and generated random number are equal we print how many attempts
                {
                    attemptCounter++;
                    System.out.println("Congrats you made the right guess after "+ attemptCounter + " attempts!");
                    break;

                }

                if(userInput<randomNum){
                    attemptCounter++;
                    System.out.print("Too low! Try again: ");

                    }
                else {
                    attemptCounter++; //else clause does the opposite of if clause
                    System.out.print("Too high! Try again: ");

                    }


                }
            catch( Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");

                    }
            }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        theGame (input);


        System.out.println("Play again? (Y/N)");

        try{
            char answer=input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);



            //toLowerCase method so that N =n = no !

            if (answer =='y') theGame (input);


            else if (answer =='n') System.out.println("Good bye");


            input.close(); //no more input data

            }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("invalid input");
        }
    }


}
```

so when the user types in the wrong type i.e not `int` it prints out `invalid input`. This is however not the problem the problem is that it prints that out infinitely. I tried adjusting the `try` `catch`blocks but it didnt help at all

Comment: You need to do something with the catch. One option is to `break` out of the loop

Comment: I think your code is working fine. what error exactly you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextInt` doesnt remove non-integer data from the input buffer so it gets recycled indefinitely unless the data is consumed. In this case an `InputMismatchException` is thrown by the method so you could write your exception block as

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input " + input.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Thank you your code made my code work perfectly. However i'd like you to explain how you thought about it i mean howd you come up with this? :)

Comment: all this information can figured out using the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt-int-): _This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value_